# how to test serial port communication in windows with rxtx?

Tags: serial-port, rxtx, serial-communication

I am using [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/) with Java to connect to serial port. But now i have to test whether the communication is working properly or not? How to do this. Do i need modem or can we test any way in my local with out modem.

this is the program i want to test http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Two_way_communcation_with_the_serial_port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows you can use a 'null modem emulator' called [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/). This registers 2 dummy com ports onto the OS, which will communicate between each other.

So, you'd need to connect to it 'twice', one for each end of the serial connection.
com0com also has variants called com2tcp & hub4com, if that's more appropriate for you.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Uh, no you don't need a modem(?).  You can use a null modem serial cable to do loopback testing from one COM port to another.  You can do this on a single PC or two different computers.  If you don't have enough COM ports, use a USB to serial converter.